# How to allow group members to create files and sub-folders and allow other group members to access the file

Tags: permissions, chown

I have created a group and added group members to it. I use Linux server whereas all other group members use Windows 10, 7 and 8.1. I have given access to the group members to create folders and files in a directory.

Problem:

1. when they create a folder or a file they become the owner of the file and folder and makes me and other users not access the file.
2. When I create a spreadsheet and when any of the team member modify it later, they become the owner of the file preventing me and other to work on it later. I had to take admin rights every time and change the ownership of the file and group name of the file so that all of us can work on it temporarily.
3. Everytime they save the file which was created by themselves, they had to save it with a new name since this file is not allowing the owner to save it with the same name or replace the existing file.

Expected solution: When a group member creates a file or a folder, or modify an existing file, they can be the owner of the file but that file should allow other users to access it, modify it.

Tried:
I can manually do it by using `sudo chown user:group [path]`
I can automate it by creating a cron job to run at the end of the day.

But I wanted to set an algorithm for a directory or a folder that whenever a file or sub folder is created in it, it should be accessible to all the group members.
I can relate that it is something to with the getfacl, but quit not sure on how it is done.

Comment: This is traditionally done using setgid on the directory, although you can also use ACLs. See for example [Make all new files in a directory accessible to a group](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12842/make-all-new-files-in-a-directory-accessible-to-a-group)

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks, will look into it.